# Outlook automatically adding in the date when I use the full stop and Enter key

Tags: microsoft-outlook, autocomplete, date

Does anyone know how to get Outlook to stop autocompleting  my dates when I use the full stop and Enter keys.  I have to enter to get to a new line but then it automatically adds in today's date.  I tried google but I can't seem to find anything relevant.

[image]

Comment: Try using <shift><enter> instead of <enter>

Answer (score 1):

[Outlook Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SR1MT.png)  Can you please try remove update automatically is checked in your outlook - This setting you will find from insert TAB